# Removing commas from strings and numbers

Tags: r, string-substitution

Using R, how do I remove commas if its a number and replace commas with a space if its a letter?:

```
  Company        | Sales   |
  -------------------------
  go, go, llc    |2,550.40 |
  tires & more   |  500    |
  l-m tech       |1,000.67 |
```

Sample data:

```
data = matrix(c('go, go,llc', 'tires & more', 'l-m technology',
 formatC(2550.40, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=2), 500, 
 formatC(1000.67, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=2)), 
 nrow=3, 
 ncol=2)
```

Expected output:

```
  Company      | Sales  |
  -----------------------
  go go llc    |2550.40 |
  tires & more |  500   |
  l-m tech     |1000.67 |
```

What I've tried:

```
data <- sapply(data, function(x){
           if (grepl("[[:punct:]]",x)){
              if (grepl("[[:digit:]]",x)){
                 x <- gsub(",","",x)
              }
              else{
                 x <- gsub(","," ",x)
              }
           }
        })

print(nrow(data)) # returns NULL
```

Comment: Is it like the `company` column would always have letters and `Sales` column numbers?

Comment: No, a few companies have numbers in them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with a nested `gsub`:

```
gsub(",", "", gsub("([a-zA-Z]),", "\\1 ", input)
```

The inner pattern matches a letter followed by a comma and replaces it with just the letter. The outer `gsub` replaces any remaining commas with spaces.

Applying it to your matrix:

```
    apply(data, 2, function(x) gsub(",", "", gsub("([a-zA-Z]),", "\\1 ", x)))
    #      [,1]             [,2]     
    # [1,] "go  go llc"     "2550.40"
    # [2,] "tires & more"   "500"    
    # [3,] "l-m technology" "1000.67"
```